# Why can't users in the "Visitors" group access my SharePoint 2010 publishing site. It works when i promote them to the "Members" group

Tags: security, sharepoint-2010

When I place a test AD account in the Visitors group they are unable to view any pages on my new intranet site. The users receives the "Error access denied" sharepoint screen and indicates that the account was able to authenticate, but that some authorisation rule is permitting it from viewing the page.

When i remove then and place them in the Members or Owners groups they are able to view the pages as well as perform the expected functions like editing content and creating subsites.

Interesting, while in only the Visitors group, users can view the "All Site Content" page that is located here: /_layouts/viewlsts.aspx but not /pages/default.aspx.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Environment info: 
1 Web application, 1 Site collection using the Publishing Portal template. A few custom master pages, lots of custom page layouts and user controls. All deployed via features.
Sharepoint 2010 Standard edition, 64bit running on Windows Server 2008 against SqlServer 2008 Enterprise Edition. Authentication is against AD, not any other forms auth providers etc.

Answer (score 5):

One likely reason for such behavior is that it tries to access a resource on a page which might not have been published to a major version. For example, if versioning was turned on on images library and an image's version is 0.1, if that image was used on version 1.0 (published) of the page, the server would deny access to the visitor and ask for credentials.

Make sure following:

1. At least one major version of the page exists (page was published at least once)
2. All resources (images, movie files etc) used on the page are published (to major version)

You can use "Draft Check" button on Page Tab of the Page's ribbon to check the unpublished resources that are used by the page.

Comment: Interesting, I click on 'Draft Check' and the yellow status bar says that 'Unpublished items are detected on the page, View the full report in a new window", so i click bring up the full report and it says that "No draft items found in this site collection"... It does say underneath that "Note: Only links and images referencing unpublished items in this site collection are shown".. Anyway i tried logging in as a Visitor and i get the same behaviour - Access denied. Thanks anyway

Comment: One quick way to figure out which individual resource on your page is Unpublished (and hence causing access denied?) is to use Fiddler tool and see all individual requests for all resources (.js, .css, image files etc). The one causing response code THER THAN 200 OK (perhaps 401 or 402) could be the culprit.

Comment: I found that it wasn't that unpublished content. Editing the permissions of the Visitors group and Adding "Browse Directories" seems to actually allow the visitors to login and view the site now. Unfortunately this means that they can see the Site Actions menu.

Comment: I found that the HTML file I references was not published. It did not have a major version. The 'detect unpublished items' did not get triggered by this. When I dug into the file tree and manually published each html file, they became available to my users.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I've finaly found out how to do this:

If you check OOB group access, you can find that Visitors group has limited number of pages where it has granted access.

1. Navigate to `/yourweb/_catalogs/masterpage`. Here you'll find many
   .aspx files (including `default.master`).
2. Open this default.master`s permissions and you see it inherits from
   Master Page Gallery.
3. Click this permissions inheritance and you can see that Master Page
   Gallery permissions are not inherited from site collection
   permissions.
4. Give here the Contribute permissions to Style Resource Readers (or
   modify it as you'd like) and all users will have access to this web
   with no permissions to edit etc..

Comment: Thank you! This was my issue, I tried checking the properties for the site but it doesn't reveal that the _catalog/masterpage has special permissions. As soon as I turned it to inherit permissions it showed everything for visitors.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and the thing I noted in your Environmental comments was the custom master pages. Go to your Site Settings and ensure that your custom master pages have been published. If you need to publish them also check the corresponding html pages after they have been published as they may need to be republished also.

This worked for me.